# attach event even if form reloaded

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I am using jQuery to  trigger a function when a hidden element `#cs_contre` of my form is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#cs_contre').gentleSelect
    ({ 
        hideOnMouseOut: false
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="cs_contre" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
          <option value="ES">Spain</option>
          <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
          <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

When my form `act_form` is reloaded, I think the event is not bound anymore. I know I can use the `on` event to bind the event to my control no matter what happens:

```
$('#act_form').on('click', '#cs_contre', function()
{
    gentleSelect({ hideOnMouseOut: false });
});
```

But there is no `click` event for the function I want to call, so I don't know how to adapt the code above. I have tried the `load` event but it does not work. 
Also, is it correct to call the function the way I do?

The function is taken from the gentleSelect project:
http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-gentleSelect/

To understand what I am doing, click on the "Select some fruit" button at the beginning of the link above. This function displays a `<select multiple=multiple></select>` in a more pretty way (many columns...).
`#cs_contre` is the hidden select control . The jquery of the project creates the button to open a drop down list, which itself is populated with the `#cs_contre` element.

If it's not clear, if you have time, please read the link above :).

With this code:

```
$(document).on('load', '#act_form', function()
{
    alert("load");
});
```

I don't see the alert, it seems that the form is never loaded, but I can see it! What is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is. You're saying you are triggering a function when a hidden element is loaded? Do you mean when the hidden element is _shown_? I can't see how the first code snippet would do that.

Comment: I have added some explanation in my original post. The element is never shown, it is used to display a customized "drop down list" with the ability to select many elements (try the link in my post).

Comment: You could try to define $(document).on('load', '#cs_contre', function(){});

Comment: @sdespont: I have added the result in my original post, this does not work :(.

Comment: @rom Hard to say why. Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution :): I call the function each time I reload the form:

```
/* display select button with hidden drop down lists for adopt variables */
function display_adopt_variables()
{
    $('#cs_contre').gentleSelect
    ({ 
        hideOnMouseOut: false
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() 
{
    display_adopt_variables()        
});



//reset act form
function reset_act_form()
{
    ...    
    display_adopt_variables()
}
```

Voilà ! :)